# LSRestore job is taking more than 1 hr to complete. Threshold time is 45min

Tags: sql-server, replication, restore, sql-server-2019, jobs

LSCopy and LSRestore job has been scheduled for every 10 mins. I got a trn file on my secondary server after every 6 min from Primary server. LSCopy is synced with LSBackup. The problem is that LSRestore job takes more than 1 hr to restore that log file. My machine configuration is 64GB RAM with 4vcpu. CPU utilization is less than 10%. Is there a way out to reduce the log restoration
time ?

Comment: What is the size of the files ?  How is teh size going to change over time ?

Comment: We're going to need wait stats and performance information to help you any further.

Comment: Perhaps it is a huge log backup file, quite simply? Also, cpu is not a good indicator since restore is mostly I/O.

Comment: Hi Rohit, the size of the files varies from 2gb to 5gb.

Comment: Hi Rohit, At 4:47PM log file size was 4.87GB, after it at 4:43PM it was of 4.68GB and after 6min its size was 3.65GB. LSRestore took 1hr to 1.45hr for every files.

Comment: Hi Tibor, size of log files vary from 2gb to 5gb. Should I add more vcpu to server for better performance? this time server has 1socket , 4vcpu and 64GB RAM. CPU utilization is between 5 to 14%

Comment: Hi Sean, find the major wait stats, wait type - LCK_M_S wait time seconds - 65716.528
wait task count - 3565 Percentage_WaitTime - 48.61                                                                  
wait type - IO_COMPLETION
Wait_Time_Seconds - 58455.046
Waiting_Tasks_Count - 22893376
Percentage_WaitTime - 43.24